# Format Dictionary using input string in python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am using below code to scrape data from website, where three fields are filled by user input.

```
import requests 
import json
  

URL = "http://example.com"
  
docs = input("Doc type: ")
fromdate = input("From: ")
todate = input("To: ")

r = requests.post(url = URL, json = {"MaxRows":0,"RowsPerPage":0,"StartRow":0,"DocTypes":'"{}"',"FromDate":'"{}"',"ToDate":'"{}"'.format(docs,fromdate,todate)})
r.json()
```

But I am getting error like this

> {'exceptionMessage': 'Input string was not in a correct format.',
> 'exceptionType': 'System.FormatException',  'message': 'An error has
> occurred.',  'stackTrace': '   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String
> str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo
> info, Boolean parseDecimal)\r\n   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String
> s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)\r\n   at
> BrowserView.Models.SearchCriteria.Parse()\r\n   at
> BrowserView.Controllers.SearchController.SearchTwo(SearchCriteria
> criteria)'}

i want the code given below

```
json = {"MaxRows":0,"RowsPerPage":0,"StartRow":0,"DocTypes":'"{}"',"FromDate":'"{}"',"ToDate":'"{}"'.format(docs,fromdate,todate)}
```

to be like this when user inputs data

```
json = {"MaxRows":0,"RowsPerPage":0,"StartRow":0,"DocTypes":"TAX","FromDate":"20201104","ToDate":"20201218"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem is only in inserting variable into your json then try this:

```
r = requests.post(url=URL, json={"MaxRows":0,"RowsPerPage":0,"StartRow":0,"DocTypes":f'{docs}',"FromDate":f'{fromdate}',"ToDate":f'{todate}'})
```

Comment: `docs`, `fromdate` and `todate` are already strings, so no need for f-strings.  Just use, for example, `"DocTypes":docs`.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
r = requests.post(url=URL, json= 
    {
      "MaxRows": 0,
      "RowsPerPage": 0,
      "StartRow": 0,
      "DocTypes": docs,
      "FromDate": fromdate,
      "ToDate": todate
     })
```

[input()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) will return each value as a string, no need for a format string.